VNCviewer - screen resolution and font size
I'm kinda new to VNCviewer and have some issues. This is on RHEL 7 based systems.
First, for regular day to day (character based) works, I use putty in my laptop with about 155 character wide and about 45 lines height. (Attached screen shots for all)
I use vncviewer to work with xterm for applications which require that (certain Oracle s/w installations, for instance)
Generally I start the vnc process as "$ vncserver -geometry 1910x960 :0" from a Linux server and then connect to that server via vncviewer and then from that xterm session, I ssh to any required Linux terminals where I need to install the s/w which requires xterm.
In my case, in the x session also, I want to have a full screen with 155 X 45, but somehow the screen size (of the x terminal / x session and not the vnviewer window) couldn't be resized to accommodate this change. And the screen width is only 80 characters. I tried with a few resolutions using "-geometry" parameter, but couldn't figure that out.
Also, I would like to set the font also, accordingly. But I couldn't change the font size also. For instance, in my putty, I use courier new font with font size 10. I couldn't change the font size.
I can invoke the menu by pressing and CTRL+right arrow to change the font to small / mediam / big only and nothing more.
Can the experts help me ?

